# How to use two $lookup in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here i am having two collection `Organizations` & `Groups` , my requirement is i want to check `oldschoolID` in Organizations table and i have to take `schoolID` & `name`.

Then i have to use `$lookup` to connect Organizations collection `schoolID` and Groups collection `otherIds.schoolID` and i have to make separate array called `group-section` and push into needed `($project)` values.

> Organizations:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c11efebd9cb4d35f47d6bd0"),
    "schoolID" : "123",
    "name" : "Abd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put one more aggregation stage $unwind between current stage 2 & 3.

```
    // Stage 2     
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Groups",
      localField: "orgID", // organization table org id
      foreignField: "otherIds.orgID",
      as: "group-section"
    }
  },
// New Stage
{
$unwind: {
path: "$group-section",
preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}
}
  // Stage 3
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "GroupContents",
      localField: "group-section.groupID",
      foreignField: "groupID",
      as: "group-section"
    }
  },
```